# Adding a character to a filename

Tags: centos, files, rename, sort

I have about 18k of files that named this way:

```
0001_3423
..
9999_9999
10000_5384
..
18401_6843
```

First part of the name is unique number, while second part is max to 9999.
I need to place prefix 0 to the first part of files which contains only 4 digits, so they could be sorted properly.

Comment: If either of the existing answers solved your problem, please select it by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in ????_*
do
  mv -- "$file" "0${file}"
done
```

Comment: Suppose 
rename ????_ 0????_ *.ext
should do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

```
rename 's/^\d{4}_\d{4}$/0$&/' *
```

Or, this,

```
rename 's/^/0/' [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```